# Forced to log out when sfDoctrineGuard denies access due to lack of permissions

Tags: symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I am using the sfDoctrineGuard module to manage permissions for my symfony project.

I have noticed the following behavior: If you are logged in as one user and then try to access something for which you don't have credentials, you will be told as much and presented with a log-in screen. If you then attempt to log-in as a *different* user you will not be able to: you keep getting the same permission denied error. It seems that you have to explicitly log-out (or close the browser) in order to delete your user credentials in the session before you can log back in as a different user.

Is this intended behavior? Or have I set something up incorrectly?

**UPDATE**. Darmen asked for some code. I did not write much code, but rather mostly did some configuration. In case it helps, here is what I did

1. Installed the sfDoctrineGuard module as per the documentation for the plugin.
2. Enabled the module by editing `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`:

   ```
   class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
   {
     public function setup()
     {
       $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');      // Add this
       $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrineGuardPlugin'); // Add this
     }
   }
   ```
3. Rebuilt the models.
4. Secured the `backend` application by editing `apps/backend/config/security.yml`:

   ```
   default:
     is_secure: true
   ```
5. I created some users, groups, and permissions. I restricted one of the modules to users or groups associated with the permission `perm_backend_edit` by adding this to `apps/backend/modules/book/config/security.yml`

   ```
   default:
     is_secure: true
     credentials: [ perm_backend_edit ]
   ```

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: What does happen exactly, when _If you then attempt to log-in as a different user you will not be able to: you keep getting the same permission denied error._ Please verify your user credentials and login form errors with the backend_dev toolbar.